# Access user computer or hosting server directory from sftp

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, sharpssh

I have a sftp server and I developed a interface website between users and sftp files using c#.NET and SharpSSH for download,upload file operations etc

Here is my problem: downloading a file from sftp to my computer works perfect. It copies the file to anywhere I want. But after I publish the website from a server, it doesn't work. Because I couldn't copy file to neither a directory in that server or client's computer. It isn't allowed default I think..

How can I solve to download a file from sftp to client computer issue using sharpssh?
Thanks..